# Visual Studio 2008, Prerequisites could not be found for bootstrapping

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, setup-deployment, prerequisites

I am having issues with the setup project for a VB.Net application, targeting .NET Framework 2. The setup project has prerequisites defined for:

```
- Crystal reports for .NET framework 2.0
- Microsoft Data Access Components 2.8
- Windows Installer 2.0
```

This application *was* working correctly at one point in Visual Studio 2008 and all the prerequisites were found. The last time that it work correctly was a few months ago. I have always had Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 installed on this machine. Recently, though, I installed MVC4 and for this to install correctly I need to install SP1 for Visual Studio 2010. Now when I go back to my VB.Net project in Visual Studio 2008 and navigate to `_properties>prerequisites_`, I see yellow triangles next to these three prerequisites with the message

> "Prerequisites could not be found for bootstrapping".

I read somewhere on the internet that the packages may be missing from the following location:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages

But when I check in this folder I see a subfolder `CrystalReports10_5` which is the correct folder for the Crystal Reports prerequisite to the best of my knowledge.

The crystal reports prerequisite is the main issue that I *have* to solve, because the application installation will definitely not be correct if this is missing. I am not sure about the other two prerequisites (I took over this application from another developer).

I would appreciate any help anyone could give to get the prerequisites for this setup project located by Visual Studio.

**UPDATE**:

I am attaching a screenshot of *Programs and Features* showing which Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 component are installed, in case these are relevant. Although, hmm, I do find it curious that Visual Studio 2008 does not seem to show a version number.

[image: Programs and Features on my Windows 7 box]